# How to fix "name 'self' is not defined" error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, self

I'm trying to learn python OOP, I am stuck with the error below.

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'self' is not defined
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/MiniProject3/test1.py", line 27, in <module>
    login = first_class (self.Bank_Users.keys(), self.Bank_Users.values())
  File "/home/khalid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/khalid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/home/khalid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

I've tried to search for similar problems  that may have been solved, but I couldn't find a way to get past this error.

```
class first_class(object):

    def __init__(self, UserName, Password, Bank_Users):
        self.UserName = UserName
        self.Password = Password
        self.Bank_Users = {"Aldo": "1234"}


    def login_or_exit(self):

        while True:
            print("Please Enter User Name")
            self.UserName = input(">> ")
            print("Please Enter Password")
            self.Password = input(">> ")

            if self.UserName in self.Bank_Users.keys() and self.Password in self.Bank_Users.values():
                print("Logging into", self.UserName)

            else:
                print("Unsuccesful!!")

login = first_class (self.Bank_Users.keys(), self.Bank_Users.values())
login.login_or_exit()
```

Comment: You can only use `self` in a context where it's defined. There's a `self` defined inside your `__init__` and `login_or_exist` functions, but not at the top-level where you're running the `first_class(self.Bank_Users.keys(), ...)`. `self` doesn't have any meaning outside of specific contexts where it's defined as a parameter or otherwise bound; we can't tell you how to fix it unless we know what you *intend* it to mean, and show code that could otherwise be expected to work.

Comment: What's the point of hardcoding `Bank_Users` inside your `__init__()`, while also taking a parameter by that name (but then ignoring it)?

Comment: BTW, in Python, it's good form to name *classes* with `CamelCase`, and members with `lower_case`. See the style guide at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: You're outside the class, outside scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this correctly might look like:

```
class BankLoginSystem(object):
    def __init__(self, bank_users):
        self.bank_users = bank_users
        self.logged_in_user = None
    def login_or_exit(self):
        while True:
            print("Please Enter User Name")
            attempted_user = input(">> ")
            print("Please Enter Password")
            attempted_password = input(">> ")
            if attempted_password == self.bank_users.get(attempted_user):
                self.logged_in_user = attempted_user
                print("Success!!")
                return
            else:
                print("Unsuccesful!!")

# the user database is independent of the implementation
bank_users = { "Aldo": "1234" }

login = BankLoginSystem(bank_users)
login.login_or_exit()
print("Logged in user is: %s" % login.logged_in_user)
```

Note that we *aren't* taking the username and password as initialization arguments to the object -- since an object can have multiple users logged in over the course of its lifetime, doing so doesn't make sense.

Similarly, things that should be kept private (like attempted passwords) we aren't storing in class member variables, but keeping strictly as locals so they don't leak out-of-scope. (In a real system you'd want your password database to have salted hashes, not real passwords, containing the damage if the password database itself leaks).

BTW, note that generally speaking, combining your I/O logic with your backend storage representation is a bad idea -- typically, you want to have pure objects modeling your domain separate and distinct from whatever interaction with users takes place.

Comment: Thank you for this. Why did you use "bank_users" in "login = BankLoginSystem(bank_users)"?

Comment: Need to get the data in somewhere, and you don't want to hardcode it in your class definition (if you did, it couldn't be swapped out with a different set of users without making a whole new class; whereas right now you could instantiate `BankLoginSystem` 5 different times with different sets of users for testing).

Comment: Makes Sense, Thanks again!